# powersell runbook to Graphical runbook

Tags: azure-runbook

I have PowerShell script runbook from that I want graphical runbook in azure.

I attached a small script for this anyone help to guide how to built graphical runbook.

```
param(
    [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $AzureResourceListParam
)

$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try {
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Write-Output "Logging in to Azure... $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId"
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
} catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection) {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
Write-Output "Credentials are accepted."
```

Comment: If your issue has been solved, could you accept it as answer? (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the details about how to build a graphical runbook are included [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-graphical-authoring-intro#graphical-runbook-procedures).

I build a graphical runbook with the same thing what your powershell script does like below.

[image]

If you want to use it directly, just download the `test.graphrunbook` file in [my Github repository](https://github.com/Joyw1/graphrunbook)(it is beyond 30000 characters limit of the answer, so I could not post it directly here), then navigate to your `Automation Account` in the portal -> `Runbooks` -> `Import a runbook` -> import the `test.graphrunbook` file -> `Create`.