# Get-AzScheduledQueryRule what is same funtion script for azurerm

Tags: azure-powershell

In az Get-AzScheduledQueryRule but in azurerm there is no query rule. I f any alternative script means pls share.

Comment: And how about your another case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57411961/powersell-runbook-to-graphical-runbook ? Does it work?

Comment: ya that problem is solved thank you very much Joy Wang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `Get-AzScheduledQueryRule` command gets the alert rule whose `SIGNAL TYPE` is `Log Search`, its resource type is `microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules`.

For the `AzureRM` module, your option is to use the [`Get-AzureRmResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.13.0) command, specify the `-ResourceType` with  `"microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules"`.

Sample:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -ResourceType "microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules" -Name "<alert rule name>" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]